# Why does this script work only if I use delay?

Tags: macos, applescript, delay

I'm writing a little script to automate the process of registering to poker tournaments while playing several other tables.
The lobby window is in the background, and in the foreground there are other tables popping out when it's time to play. So in order to register I need to set the lobby in foreground (ctrl + 1) and prevent the application to pop out other tables (I've used a repeat cycle to do this, but I'm not sure if it's the best way).

I can't understand why, when I put those delay 0.5 or 0.2, the script works as expected, otherwise if I run the script without them it doesn't work (doesn't click on the registration button in the lobby).

This is critical because in those 0.5 seconds there could be other tables popping and stealing focus from the main lobby. Note that I'm using pixel coordinates to click on the button since it's a non-Cocoa application and doesn't let me click the button easily.

How can I solve this?

```
--REGISTRATION PROCESS
--make sure we complete the reg process without other tables popping up and stealing focus from the tourney reg window
set done to false
repeat until done is true
    delay 0.5
    --Lobby focused
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontmost of process "PokerStarsIT" to true
        keystroke "1" using command down
        delay 0.2
    end tell

    --Start the registration process: click "register" button.
    tell application "PokerStarsIT"
        do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (xCoordinate as text) & " -y " & (yCoordinate as text) & " -rightClick"
        set done to true                
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it this way. Notice that I'm using the name of window 1 as "Lobby". Make sure to enter the actual name of the window that is the Lobby window there. You'll also notice that the "do shell script" command is not inside of the PokerStarsIT application tell block of code. "do shell script" is an applescript command, not a PokerStarsIT command. Also I think you should do "-leftClick" instead of "-rightClick". Good luck.

```
tell application "PokerStarsIT" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "PokerStarsIT"
        repeat
            keystroke "1" using command down
            if name of window 1 is "Lobby" then exit repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

--Start the registration process: click "register" button.
do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (xCoordinate as text) & " -y " & (yCoordinate as text) & " -leftClick"
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I don't know why it works partially, it clicks correctly only the first time, then it doesn't click when registering for the second tournament. Oh, and it is unable to find POSIX path if I run it as you wrote. However there maybe other errors in the script that influence its correct behaviour. I've pasted the script here: http://pastebin.com/uw6vHcYA. If you will you can take a look and tell me why this doesn't work as expected. Notice that in a perfect world no "delay" should exist in the script. :)